# Is that possible to add two condition on system.linq ? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

is that possible to add two condition on system.ling like code below :

```
int index = Playerx.items.FindIndex (j => j.itemID == IdItem.itemID && j.itemStock < 20);
```

the code i have add two condition in FindIndex function.

That is to check to find itemID at Playerx.items and Playerx.items itemStock is < 20.

Is That possible ?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add as many conditions as you want.

In this line:

```
(j => j.itemID == IdItem.itemID && j.itemStock < 20)
```

`j.itemID == IdItem.itemID && j.itemStock < 20` - it is delegate and previous line can be replaced:

```
(j => {return j.itemID == IdItem.itemID && j.itemStock < 20;})
```

so, it is body of delegate (method). In method you can use any number of conditions.